# Difference in zoom level between data view and print layout QGIS

Tags: qgis, basemap

I am working with a Stamen Toner base map. I want to print/export the same extent and sizing of labels that I can see in the main window on QGIS. When I zoom to the scale I want and add it to the print layout, the basemap becomes extremely zoomed out.

Is this caused by the scale/size of the Stamen tiles, or is there a way around this so I can print the exact extent I want?

[image: Extent I want]

[image: Extent after adding to print layout]

Answer (score 0):

Check these buttons in the map item properties (they move the current extents/scale from one window to another):

[image]

See video: https://ibb.co/D95PHLt